# QML: default binding for derived property

Tags: qt, binding, qml

I want to reimplement the following QML component (MyComp.qml) in C++:

```
QtObject {
    property bool a: true
    property bool b: false
    // default: binding to a && b
    property bool derived: a && b
}
```

Which looks like this:

```
class MyComp : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyComp(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_PROPERTY(bool a MEMBER a_ NOTIFY aChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool b MEMBER b_ NOTIFY bChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool derived MEMBER derived_ NOTIFY derivedChanged)
signals:
    void aChanged();
    void bChanged();
    void derivedChanged();
private:
    bool a_ {true};
    bool b_ {false};
    // I want to set up a default binding derived = a && b that is
    // overridable, just like in the QML component; probably in
    // the impl. of the default ctor
    bool derived_ {true};
}
```

This works, except for what's described in the comment for `derived`.
I.e. in QML, the following instantiations should all work:

```
MyComp {
    id: default_behavior
    // should use default a && b binding for derived
}

MyComp {
    id: fixed_value
    derived: false
}

MyComp {
    id: bind_to_other
    derived: a && b && some.other.value
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When you say, "The translation to C+++ is straight forward" .. how .. ? what did you try ?

Comment: Tried to clarify it a bit. I want to programmatically setup a default binding for MyComp, just as I do in the QML component with the line "property bool derived: a && b""

Comment: Are you saying that the default_behavior doesn't work like you want, but fixed_value and bind_to_other do work like you want?

Comment: default_behavior cannot work because I don't know how to programmatically create a Binding from derived to "a && b" in C++ as I do in QML with the line "property bool derived: a && b" (as a default, preconfigured binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I don't have any Qt environment to my avail, this will be just a rough sketch of an idea, to solve the problem.

1. Don't use MEMBER-Properties, but those with `SETTER` and `GETTER`
2. Write a slot:
   `void onAorBChanged() { setDerived(getA() && getB()); }`
3. Connect that slot to the signals `aChanged()` and `bChanged()` in the Constructor.
   `connect(this, &MyComp::aChanged, this, &MyComp::onAorBChanged);`
   `connect(this, &MyComp::bChanged, this, &MyComp::onAorBChanged);`
4. Disconnect that slot from both (all) signals, once the `SETTER` of `derived` is called.
   `disconnect(this, 0, this, &MyComp::onAorBChanged)`

---

Of course you need to have two setters for `derived` - the one you call in *2.* is not supposed to disconnect the slot. Only the one you use for the `Q_PROPERTY`

---

Probably, the more fail-safe solution is, to do it in QML.
So you define your `CppMyComp` in C++, then you create a QML Component `MyComp`

```
// MyComp.qml
CppMyComp {
    derived: a && b
}
```

which you then use in later:

```
MyComp {
    id: defaul_behaviour
    // derived is bound, but the binding can be easily overridden.
}
MyComp {
    id: fixed_value
     derived: false
}
MyComp {
    id: bind_to_other
    derived: a && b || someOther
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the brute force solution I was afraid of. Hoped there would be a way to programmatically create QQmlBindings. Will award bounty once SO allows it ...